# Uninstalling UserPassChange script

Tags: google-apps-script

I installed a script http://www.googleappsscript.org/home/force-google-apps-users-to-change-password-periodically. Idea was to force Google Apps - users in my organisation to change their passwords every 3 months. Script works well. However, there are certain accounts whose password must remain the same and therefore I would need to uninstall the script.

Would anyone be able to help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method would be to add 3 exceptions to this list using an `IF/ELSE` statement, and a method to ignore the 3 users. I'll provide you with an example in C#, since that's the language I'm most fluent in:

```
if (username == "VIP1")
  { ignore(string username)}
else if (username == "VIP2")
  { ignore(string username)}
else if (username == "VIP3")
  { ignore(string username)}
else
  { passchange()}
```

You'd also need to provide an overload for the user in the `ignore()` method. If you have a relatively small userbase (under, say, 200 users), this idea would be very effective. If you have a larger userbase, this may be a bit of an expensive process, since you have to run through the entire userlist for each iteration of the if/else statement.

Answer (score 0):

Users that installed the script and authorized it have received an email with uninstall instruction. This message shows a link to uninstall the script, this link is easy to re-build if ever they lost it :
 use the link of the script and replace the ending part with /manage/uninstall.

for example, this script url

```
https://script.google.com/d/1DsMPFCPo-870TuOFM4Sg9BY0c28gyj8NY_________n0upV1AOG2MAsxy/edit?usp=drive_web
```

would be changed to

```
https://script.google.com/d/1DsMPFCPo-870TuOFM4Sg9BY0c28gyj8NY_________n0upV1AOG2MAsxy/manage/uninstall
```

that will direct the user to a page looking like this :

[image]